# Как копировать фрагмент exe файла в другой exe файл, чтобы он исполнялся?

Tags: python, exe

Как можно копировать фрагмент exe файла в другой exe файл так, чтобы исполнялась часть копируемого exeшника, а уже потом оригинального?

Comment: Это называется компьютерный вирус.

Comment: Да, я хочу понять эту технологию

Answer (score 1):

Вот [пошаговая инструкция](http://www2.inf.h-brs.de/~ikarim2s/how2injectcode/code_inject.html). Можете использовать на свой страх и риск.

Вообще нужно уверенное знание ассемблера, архитектуры процессора, структуры бинарного файла и прочих штук. Могу посоветовать изучить Танненбаума "Архитектура ЭВМ".